# Changing object embed source via jquery

Tags: jquery, flash

I need to be able to load up different flash files when users click an image in my gallary. My current solution works perfectly fine in Firefox, but Chrome and IE are not working and it isn't giving any error messages.

I use jquery to change the embed source

```
$('#flash embed').attr('src', msg.d);


  <object id="flash">
                <embed src="" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="800" height="600"></embed>
  </object>
```

Comment: That code works in Chrome for me. Are you sure the problem isn't with `msg.d`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a few solutions. I ended up using the second one.

**Method 1:**
I insert the entire object tab with embed dynamically. That seems to fix flash loading issues in Chrome and IE.

**Method 2:**
I found a jquery flashloader plugin that is simple to use and works well.
http://jquery.lukelutman.com/plugins/flash/

Method 3
Use jquery swfObject
http://jquery.thewikies.com/swfobject/examples

Answer (score 0):

I have used the same solution as you to do the same and mine works perfectly in all browsers, do you think it might be your click event? Try to alert some messages to see where it actually gets to in the code.

Note my code below:

```
$("object embed").attr("src", id);
```

Comment: would seem kind of strange that the click event works in firefox and opera, but not ie and chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for embeding:

```
 <object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="800" height="600" id="flash">
 <embed src="" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="800" height="600" />
 </object>
```

and this for switching the swf file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#galleryImageID').click(function() {
        $("#flash>embed").attr('src', msg.d);
    });
});
```

You could also use [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/).