# Change src attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change the src attribute of an embed object. I have:

```
<embed class="flash "id="flash" src="swf/pano.swf?panoSrc=images/a.jpg" 
                     allowFullScreen="true" 
                     width="1280" height="640" quality="high" 
                     pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" 
                     type="application/x-shockwave-flash" bgcolor="#DDDDDD"/>
```

and I've tried

```
function change() 
{
   document.getElementById("flash").setAttribute('src', 'swf/pano.swf?panoSrc=b.jpg');
}
```

but it didn't work in Chrome, "only" in Firefox, IE and Opera. How can I fix it (to make it work in Chrome)? Did I do anything wrong?

EDIT: here is the whole HTML file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function change() {
            document.getElementById("flash").setAttribute('src', 'swf/pano.swf?panoSrc=a.jpg');
        }
    </script>

</head>
<body>


    <embed class="flash" id="flash" src="swf/pano.swf?panoSrc=images/sau.jpg" allowFullScreen="true" 
                     width="1280" height="640" quality="high" 
                     pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" 
                     type="application/x-shockwave-flash" bgcolor="#DDDDDD"/>

     <script>
         change();
     </script>

</body>
```

Link to the page: http://chin.comli.com/test.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Move your script call to be AFTER the code it's intended to affect, or put it in a window.onload call. As you have it it's trying to execute on an element before it exists.</strike>

Long story short, based on [Changing object embed source via jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7072065/changing-object-embed-source-via-jquery), [Dynamically change embedded video src in IE/Chrome (works in Firefox)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985205/dynamically-change-embedded-video-src-in-ie-chrome-works-in-firefox), [JavaScript: Changing src-attribute of a embed-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493706/javascript-changing-src-attribute-of-a-embed-tag), and http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=69648, it looks like this is a bug in Chrome and the only workaround is to remove the entire `<embed>` element, and then re-insert it with the changed src.

Comment: I see. But even after doing that it still doesn't work. I edited the code. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Don't use webmatrix to fix this, debug it in Chrome or Firefox and use the built in dev tools or a plugin to see any errors. As you can see by this fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/AJDuY/, the code works, so there's something else going on.

Comment: oh, I just found out that it works in firefox, but not in Chrome, and I always use Chrome to preview the result. Pretty weird...

Comment: how can I use the dev's tool in Chrome? Sorry I'm a total newbie

Comment: Hit F12 to open them and choose the console. Then reload the page.

Comment: After reloading the page the console is still blank and doesn't show anything

Comment: Is your page public? If it works in most other browsers it should work in Chrome. Try clearing the cache etc and restarting Chrome.

Comment: Here is the link:http://chin.comli.com/test.html
You can try it in chrome and firefox to see the difference

Comment: This may be more of a flash embed code issue than a script issue. The code runs fine in Chrome and changes the source but it appears as if the embed isn't working properly.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18266/discussion-between-chin-and-j08691)

Answer (score 3):

You need to invoke your function.

`change();`

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LUfUx/

Comment: Needs to be after the `embed` so that the `document.getElementById` will be able to find it in the code.

Comment: Yep, what bree said. Right before the closing </body> tag is usually the best

Comment: it didn't work in Chrome, "only" in Firefox, IE and Opera. Here's the link: http://chin.comli.com/test.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function change() {
   document.getElementById("flash").src =  'swf/pano.swf?panoSrc=b.jpg';
   // OR  document["flash"].src =  'swf/pano.swf?panoSrc=b.jpg';
}
```

Comment: Why not remove the embed tag.. Insert the new source and inject it into your DOM again.. Maybe that might help

Comment: Also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2493706/javascript-changing-src-attribute-of-a-embed-tag